# PostgreSQL Transition: Comparing Timestamps to days

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I am currently transitioning from an older version of SQL Server to a PostgreSQL environment. I am having trouble finding a way to compare a timestamp's age to a set value. This is in the where clause as the goal is to take a stored timestamp and find the difference between it and the current time and then see if that is greater than 90 days old.

The original SQL Server Query:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, stored_timestamp,GETDATE())>90
```

Current Failed PostgreSQL Attmepts:

```
(stored_timestamp - current_timestamp) > stored_timestamp + interval '90 Days'
```

I have also used other forms of grabbing current times and type casting them without the interval add on and generally run into the same error.  The error most commonly received is "operator does not exist: interval > timestamp" or something of the sort where it shows I can not use the > to compare an interval to other forms of time/date data.

Comment: `(stored_timestamp - current_timestamp) > interval '90 Days'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward but naive approach would be:

```
stored_timestamp < current_timestamp - interval '90 day'
```

---

**But** that would not exactly behave the same. From the [SQL server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> This function returns the count [...] of the specified **datepart boundaries crossed** between the specified `startdate` and `enddate`.

Typically, in SQL Server:

```
select datediff(day, '2023-04-28 23:59:59', '2023-04-29 00:00:00')
```

Returns `1`, since a day boundary was crossed (actually: reached) during this 1 second span.

You don't get the same behavior in Postgres, which we can see if we compute the date difference with `extract`:

```
select extract( 
  day from (
      '2023-04-29 00:00:00'::timestamp 
    - '2023-04-28 23:59:59'::timestamp
  )
)
```

Returns `0`, because a 1 second interval has 0 days.

---

*If* you want the same behavior in Postgres, then a simple way to proceed is to cast the timestamp to a date first (... at the cost of efficienty, unless you specifically optimize for it):

```
stored_timestamp::date < current_date - interval '90 day'
```

Comment: Given that the concept of an interval is expressed in postgres, the naive thing that I would have tried would be `current_timestamp - stored_timestamp > interval '90 day'`. And [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) suggest that might work (but is incorrect for other reasons that you articulate above). Is there an _a priori_ reason why that's a Bad Idea™?

Comment: @BenThul: that has the same behavior as the example I gave; it gives an interval, not a count of boundaries crossings.

Comment: Right - my question was whether it did have the same behavior as your first example you gave. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help all.  "stored_timestamp::date < current_date - interval '90 day'" seems to have fixed my error and is giving the correct result for the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Server operation

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, stored_timestamp,GETDATE())>90
```

in PostgreSQL would be

```
extract( day from (current_timestamp -stored_timestamp)) > 90
```

in order to do a comparison between integers